# Why might an animation curve *not* affect the pose?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have a mesh with an attached animation, but some of the animation curves do not seem to be moving the bones. It's such a basic problem, I figure there must be some basic Blender feature or setting I'm not dealing with properly. Here's an example:

[image]

This frame is before this bone (NPC Neck5) starts moving, the Y Euler rotation is 0 as the graph shows. (The gizmo is in local orientation.) Now advance a few frames:

[image]

At this point the Y rotation is 30 degrees, and that's what the graph shows. But the bone hasn't rotated around the Y axis at all.

What should I be checking for to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The rotation mode of the bone has to match the rotation mode of the curve. Setting it to "Euler" made things start happening.